# Azure private DNS zone resolving

Tags: azure, dns, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway

We have a private DNS zone setup for the zone project.local. For app service instances living in an app service environment, each service has its own record pointing to the load balancer in front of the service (so all have the same IP).

We have an App Gateway instance linked to a public IP in front to make this all publiccally available. The gateway is available via a public URL and routes the request to the load balancer.

Now what we see is the following:

- From external, everything is fine. We can get to the services using the external URL, gateway forwards it and all is well.
- From internal, we want to use the **internal** DNS address set in the private zone. This is not working, calls from service to service throw an error stating that the host URL could not be resolved.
- When I log into a VM in the same vNET or use the Kudu console, I'm able to resolve the DNS address to the correct IP. What I do notice is that when using nslookup, it says it's getting a non authoritative answer.

It's very hard to get any more information for debug purposes. We're not sure why resolving isn't working as per documentation these records should work for all of the components in the same vNET. The authoritative error might be related, but again: not sure. So any ideas on what else to check would be highly appreciated.

Disclaimer: I also have a support ticket open for the same question, but wanted to put this out there to see if there's anyone else who might have encountered the same since this is pretty new tech.

Comment: Azure private DNS is used for azure internal names of cloud services, like VM, webApp and so on. You can do nothing with the private DNS zone because is manged by Azure and you cannot change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure DNS Private Zones are able to resolve names between VMs and Cloud services. It does not look like it can be used by Azure Web Apps or Azure App Services at this time.

[You can see more information on name resolution for resources in Azure Virtual Networks Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances).

If you would like to request this feature be added to DNS Private Zones, [you can leave your feedback Here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking?category_id=77466).